# Add different listeners for text in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView in which I have set some text:

```
lblText.setText("Hello How Are You");
```

Now I want it in the following way:

Whenever I click on Hello, a `Toast` should be displayed saying "Hello".
Whenever I click on How, a `Toast` should be displayed saying "How".

And so on.

How to check on which word I clicked and do different things for different words in a `TextView`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982241/android-clickable-textview-how-to-make-multiple-click-regions-on-text-and-catch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use a `SpannableString` if you do not want to have more than 1 `TextView`.

Edit:

For every String you can register a ClickableSpannable, for instance:

```
private class MyClickableSpannable extends ClickableSpan {

    private final String mStringToShow;


    public MyClickableSpannable(String stringToShow) {
        mStringToShow = stringToShow;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
         Toast.makeText(context, mStringToShow, Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and to set the listener:

```
String myString = "Hello How Are You"; 
String hello = "Hello";
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(myString);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(
   new MyClickableSpannable(hello), startIndexOfHello,
   startIndexOfHello + hello.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: How will I set listener for it. Can you direct me to an example?

Comment: @Blackbelt You are too fast. :-) while answering this kinda questions. :-)

Comment: @Blackbelt i think OP wants a genaral solution of getting a word at particular x,y point of a TextView

Comment: @pskink `String.indexOf()` is what he needs

Comment: @blackbelt i think he meant that he has MotionEvent and based on getX/Y he wants to find out the word in a TextView corresponding to that point

Comment: @pskink how do you know it? I read the question again but what he wants is to have a different onCliclListener for each word (imo)

Comment: @blackbelt its my inner voice ;) there are too many guys using Toasts instead of Log.d and i think this is the case

Comment: @pskink `How to check on which word I clicked and do different things for different words`, imo from this statement he wants a different onClickListener for every word

Answer (score 1):

This is working example .Understand it and apply it in your code as per requirement.

```
  SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello How Are You");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
           //toast hello
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan2 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
          // toast how
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan3 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
           //toast are
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan4 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
           //toast you
        }
    };
    tView.setText(ss);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan2, 5, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan3, 9, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan4, 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It worked for me very well.

```
  SpannableString SpanString = new SpannableString(
            "Hello How Are You");

    ClickableSpan hello = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    ClickableSpan how = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

          Toast.makeText(this, "how is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    SpanString.setSpan(hello, 0, 6, 0);
    SpanString.setSpan(how, 6, 9, 0);


    lblText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    lblText.setText(SpanString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);      
    Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("Hello How Are You");   
span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        Log.d("main", "Helo clicked");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } }, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
span.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {  
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {  
       Log.d("main", "how clicked");
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "how clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   } }, 6, 9, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(span); 
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```