# Multiple Hyperlinks in TextView in XML

Tags: html, textview, click

I have to develop an android application with a sign and sign out page. In that I have a privacy policy and terms and services for that I need to add a text view with single HTML text with both the sentences user click on privacy policy redirect to one activity if a user clicks on terms and conditions redirect to another activity how can we do please help me.

Comment: Please share your code and ui snippet to understand , what you actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand you have to use [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) in your code, just go through with the SpannableStringBuilder Class.

ref: [Android Clickable TextView How To Make Multiple Click Regions on Text And Catch Region Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982241/android-clickable-textview-how-to-make-multiple-click-regions-on-text-and-catch)