# How to give underline and color for a specific word in string and give a click event on that particular word?

Tags: java, android

The String is

```
Or Login to Place your Order
```

I want `Login` word in diffrent color with underline. Also want `click event` on `Login` word

I wanted to do it using single `TextView`. Can I do it using single `TextView`?

Comment: check this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969789/clickable-word-inside-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
String orLoginString = "Or Login to Place your Order";

SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(orLoginString);

ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() 
{

       @Override
       public void onClick(View textView) {

              //Your code onclick of underline string

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.updateDrawState(ds);
             //You change the color of underline string. 
             //You can make underline visible or invisible
        }
};  


redSpannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, 3, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourtextview.setText(redSpannable);

loginSelectionFirstTimeLaunching.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```