# Clickable words in a TextView - how to?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to create an Android app with php SQL database,
which will have a paragraph with some news.
I managed to connect MySQL to Android app and the data is showing in app.

The problem is that I am trying to create a clickable word.
In a paragraph clicking any word to show a toast with the same word.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Here is your solution available already visit this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969789/clickable-word-inside-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look at Android's Spannable. It allows for styling text and could give you the ability to make certain words clickable. Here is a [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) talking about Spannable. Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable).